# When should one use cf push vs cf push -p

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have seen that when you want to specify a specific deployment artifact you use "cf push -p". When should I use "cf push" vs "cf push -p" when I am not using a manifest file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you're using `cf push` you've to mention the app path like `-p: target/sampleapp.jar` in manifest.yml.
- You're deploying apps without manifest.yml then `-p` flag is mandatory like `cf push -p target/sampleapp.jar`

Comment: One additional option.  It's OK to not use the `-p` argument if you simply want to push whatever is in the current directory.  With `cf push` the path defaults to the current directory so if you want to push everything in your current directory then no path is necessary.